# I am working with React react-widget. I wanted to limit the time between 7:00am to 18:00pm. Is there a way to achieve this?

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, react-widgets

I am working with React react-widget. I wanted to limit the time between 7:00am to 18:00pm. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
  <DateTimePicker 
            onChange={(val) => {    
                    var temp = moment.utc(val);
                    onChangeDateTimePicker(temp.toISOString());                          
            }}
            format={(DATETIME_DISPLAY_FORMAT)} time={true} min={new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))} />
```

Comment: Which `DateTimePicker` library you are using?

Comment: https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/

Comment: You can use `min` and `max` props. Let me add an example.

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what you will ? What is the LIMIT ? Can you describe more clearly your example that is described in your Image ? Please suppress image that refer to another site and put the full description in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Moment from "moment";
import momentLocalizer from "react-widgets-moment";
import DateTimePicker from "react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker";
// Add the css styles...
import "react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css";

Moment.locale("en");
momentLocalizer();

const today = Moment();

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <DateTimePicker
    time
    date
    min={today.set({ hour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 }).toDate()}
    max={today.set({ hour: 18, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0 }).toDate()}
  />,
  rootElement
);
```

You can check out the example https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-surf-ydu2y.

This just restricts `min` and `max` for particular day. This doesn't work like restricting `time` across all the dates.

I think that is not possible with `react-widgets DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **min** and **max** properties to set your Limits.

The [DateTimePicker API](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/) tells you how to use it.

**[min](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/#min):**

> type: Date default: new Date(1900, 0, 1)
>
> The minimum Date that can be selected. Min only limits selection, it
>   doesn't constrain the date values that can be typed or pasted into the
>   widget. If you need this behavior you can constrain values via the
>   onChange handler.

Example:

```
let { DateTimePicker } = ReactWidgets;

let widget = (   <DateTimePicker 
    min={new Date()}   /> )

render(widget);
```

**[max](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/#max):**

> type: Date default: new Date(2099, 11, 31)
>
> The maximum Date that can be selected. Max only limits selection, it
>   doesn't constrain the date values that can be typed or pasted into the
>   widget. If you need this behavior you can constrain values via the
>   onChange handler.

let { DateTimePicker } = ReactWidgets;

```
let widget = (
  <DateTimePicker 
    max={new Date()}
  />
)

render(widget);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround - to empty timeList options if time out of range and hide empty options by css style.

css

```
  .rw-list-option:empty {
    display: none;
  }
```

component:

```
    <DateTimePicker
      {...tail}
      timeComponent={({ value, text }) => {
        return value.getHours() >= 7 && value.getHours() <= 18 ? text : '';
      }}
    />
```